# How to access InputDStream data?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, apache-kafka

I'm pretty new with scala and spark. I'm sending string messages from kafka (real) to spark (local), but how can I access them? For example, I want a list of strings with all my messages. I ended up for only printing them:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val ssc =  new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
val directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder ](ssc, kafkaParams, Set[String]("testTopic"))
directKafkaStream.print() //I can see it in console, but how to get my message string?
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/InputDStream.html), an InputDStream is a subclass of DStream. This means that you can access the InputDStream as if it was just a DStream.

You can "get" your message string just by iterating over the RDD, with something like:

```
directKafkaStream.foreachRDD { rdd => 
  rdd.foreach { content => 
    // code to handle the string here
  }
}
```

In general, it depends on the type you expect (e.g., a custom Avro record), but as in your case you are dealing with strings, it should be enough to treat the rdd as a collection of string[s].

In theory, you don't even need to iterate over the RDDs with a separate .foreachRDD if you want to apply a transformation (e.g., `filter`, ...). For example, if you want to filter all strings containing a specific word, you can use:

```
val infoLines = directKafkaStream.filter { line =>
  line.contains("INFO")
}
```

Note that `infoLines` will still return a `DStream[String]`, so you will still have the same initial problem: *how to access a single string?* You need to understand that DStreams and RDD are the high level data abstractions that Spark and Spark Streaming use - normally you will first operate on those with transformations, then you will apply actions (e.g., `saveAsTextFile`) - rarely a `println` statement.

However, judging from your question, it seems that you need to read some docs about Spark Streaming: the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#discretized-streams-dstreams) is a good resource (although some books, like Learning Spark, might also help you understand).

Comment: Treating rdd as string gives me something like "KafkaRDD[125] at createDirectStream at MyKafkaSparkExample.scala:45"           `directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
        println(rdd.toString())
      })`